# Does MIPS III really take advantage of binary backwards compatibility

Tags: assembly, 64-bit, mips, cpu-architecture, backwards-compatibility

I read some articles about MIPS, and they said that MIPS III is a backwards compatible extension of MIPS II, which means a legal MIPS II program is also an legal MIPS III program and should have the same behaviour.

I think this is different from ARM or X86. For ARM, AArch64 has a totally different encoding from Arm32 and Thumb; for X86 many instructions have the same encoding in both X86-32 and X86-64, but there are also some differences like opcode 40~4F is used for REX prefix instead of INC/DEC. Since there are differences between 32bits ISA and 64bits ISA in ARM and X86, they both take the approach that a process can be 32bits or 64bits but not both, and use a state to indicate whether the processor should use 32bits ISA or 64bits ISA.

I believe MIPS III should have advantage in some aspects, since it sacrifice the opportunity to reorganize ISA. For example like the possibility to link 32bits library and 64bits library together. I tried but failed, however.

So the questions is: does MIPS III really take advantage of binary backwards compatibility? What makes MIPS designer decided to keep full binary backwards compatibility?

Comment: Linking 32 and 64 libraries also requires matching ABI, which is certainly not going to happen. How would the 32 bit library access data on the 64 bit stack?

Comment: Original MIPS was/is highly RISC, with lots of unused opcodes (and `func` field values in R-type instructions) left over.  They were able to simply use those, and keeping the existing 32-bit operand-size instructions at the same opcodes apparently wasn't a problem for the design, so no reason not to.

Comment: But `addiu $sp, $sp, -16` to reserve space would be a problem if `$sp` is not a 32-bit sign-extended pointer, as @Raymond says.  You could deref it ok like `lw $t0, 0($sp)` (MIPS always uses the full register width for pointers), but adjusting it (especially without truncating it) is a problem if outside the low32.  So you could conceivably design a 64-bit ABI could call into 32-bit code, but only with 32-bit pointers.  So it would probably have to be an ILP32 ABI, unless you specially allocated all pointers that 32-bit code would ever see.